# Leaflet only one placemark visible at exact location, whereas is more than 1 there

Tags: leaflet, geojson, google-earth

I have a problem, because sometimes on my GeoJSON layer plotted into the Leaflet map more than 1 placemarks has been assigned to one exact location (by postcode).

The problem is, that only one of them is visible, whereas there is at least 3-4 another ones.

For example in Google Earth the problem is solved like this: when you hover one placemark, then you can see another ones hidden under the same location, as per in the picture below:

[image]

In leaflet this situation not occur and I see only 1 placemark only instead.

I was searching some stuff regarding to this problem and found a following examples:

http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/demo.html

https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet

http://ivansanchez.github.io/Leaflet.Marker.Stack/demos/color_ramps.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813139/leaflet-map-with-multiple-marker-on-exact-same-position

but they don't really solve this problem

In turn, the links below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168558/multiple-marker-on-exact-same-position-on-a-leaflet-map/22173475

they are focused on the markercluster, which I don't need.

My situation looks like this:

[image]

where as you can see (after the onclick marker trigger) you see 2 jobs on the same location, whereas only 1 appear (always the same in addition).

Could you give me some hint, what should I tweak in the code, to make it pretty much the same, as it's in Google Earth?

Comment: You say that you don't need markercluster - why are you so sure of that? IMO it's the easiest way to display custom symbols (e.g. concatenating IDs) from overlapping data. See also https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#clusteringdecluttering for completeness.

Comment: I would rather to achieve the effect like here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249743/leaflet-js-dealing-with-a-lot-of-markers-in-a-single-co-ordinate where is something like spiderfy effect in the image attached. How can I achieve it?

Comment: The answer to that is "with MarkerCluster".

Comment: I know, but the image shown with this circle-looking markers is good for me and I would like to achieve that instead of marker cluster. Is that possible?

Comment: It's possible, but I bet that it'll take several times more effort, time and custom code than just using MarkerCluster. (i.e. rolling out *your own* cluster-like algorithm to detect data points close enough to each other and do a *custom* spiderify-like display). Also, note that the question you linked to is about MarkerCluster.

Comment: I used marker cluster, and eventually I am happy. Thank you for an advice then. Rgds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I used leaflet-markercluster plugin and implemented into my GeoJSON layers as per the example below:

https://jsfiddle.net/m6jr7e0p/

[image]